# How to get the parent ID for a git commit from the Visual Studio Online REST API

Tags: git, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I'd like to pull commit data for my repos from the Visual Studio REST API. [Documentation](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/integrate/api/git/commits) seems clear enough, but I don't see how to get the parent references between the commits.

Edit:
I see that when I [request a single commit](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/integrate/api/git/commits#GetacommitJustthecommit), the response contains a `parents` array with the IDs of the parent commits. However, when I request a collection of commits, this information seems to be missing.

Comment: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/integrate/api/git/commits#GetacommitJustthecommit. Isn't it the `treeId` property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The API only returns some basic information when you use it to get a list of commits. To get more detailed information, you need to get them one by one with "[Get a commit](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/integrate/api/git/commits#Getacommit)" for now.

Comment: I see. Clearly the answer to my question, so I'll accept. But to me, the parent IDs seem like core information about a git commit. Up there with the commit message, the SHA and the commiter. The APIs of GitHub, Bitbucket and Atlassian Stash all return this information in lists of commits.